# What is the purpose of the bluetooth LE 'namepsace' descriptor?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

The BLE [Characteristic Presentation Format Descriptor](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.characteristic_presentation_format.xml) defines several metadata fields associated with the characteristic attribute exposed by a GATT server.

When the `Namespace` field (2nd to bottom in the table) is set to `1` then the following field `Description` is defined by the Bluetooth SIG as [Namespace Descriptions](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/gatt-namespace-descriptors).

Does anyone know what these Namespace Descriptions refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GATT Bluetooth Namespace Description](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/gatt-namespace-descriptors) is an optional enumeration used when you want to give some context to the Characteristic Value.

When the Namespace field of the [Characteristic Presentation Format descriptor](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.characteristic_presentation_format.xml) is set to 0x01 the Description field assume one of predefined meanings defined by [the specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/gatt-namespace-descriptors).

If for example you have a BLE server device with two temperature sensors, one inside and one outdoor,
you may use 0x010F (internal) and 0x0110 (external) as Description values for give context to the measured temperatures.

Actually Namespace permitted values are 0 (no description) and 1 (enumerated value specified by Bluetooth SIG), whereas 2-255 values are reserved for future uses (for example to define custom meaning to the Description field)

Comment: Can you point me to link where are the 7 bytes of Characteristic Presentation Format descriptor defined, i am having hard time finding those...

Comment: @Laukik
There are many referances, here is one detailed:
https://github.com/oesmith/gatt-xml/blob/master/org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.characteristic_presentation_format.xml